# Best name for the option of adding item to multiple lists or a newly created list

Tags: terminology, multi-selection, drop-down-list, options, indicator

I have a book that can be added to multiple reading lists or to a newly created one. The name of the option that does it is “Add to Reading List”.  What would be the best name for such an option so it better suggests that it’s not just for adding to existing but also to newly created lists?

In addition, what would be the best way to indicate that a book is already in (some) list(s), so it can easily be differentiated from books that haven’t been added to any list?

[image]

Comment: After clicking the button, what does the system show to select an existing list or create a new one?

Comment: It will show a list of existing reading lists in i.e. drop-menu or modal overlay and letting you choose lists to add to (i.e. via checkboxes). It will also show the option for creating a _new_ reading lists (i.e. at the bottom, always visible).

Comment: Thanks. Also do you want to indicate in which list the book is, or simply that it is in some other list (and I guess the number of lists too?)?

Comment: No, the simple indication that it is in some list(s) is fine. I did want to add the no. of the lists but since the database is huge the developers found it’s a costly operation, so only the indication that it is in _some_ list(s), that’s all (and the proper name for the option in relation to it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Add to list" is used in some apps such as Spotify, and I think it doesn't create confusion. It tells the user what the *final action* is, which is to add the item to a list. That said, if the distinction has to be made before the user clicks the button you could use two buttons, one for each final destination:

- "Add to new Reading List" (non-existent list)
- "Add to a Reading List" / "Add to one of the Reading Lists" (existent list)

To indicate that it is already in some list:

- "**Add to another Reading List**": Implies it is already in at least one list.
- "Add to a Reading List (**already in X lists**)": The last part of the message doesn't need to be in the button. Although you comment this is not possible, it would be better as the user could check right there with a click or hover to how many lists and which the book already belongs.

Comment: “Add to another Reading List” is a great suggestion, many thanks. The counter _is_ possible, but it’s costly operation, therefore, I’d rather go easy on performance (18 million books and counting).